# SingleChildScrollView is not working properly

Tags: flutter, scroll, singlechildscrollview

I wrap the whole body with SingleChildScrollView, it works when i scroll down, but can't able to scroll up.

here is the code

```
body:SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    child: 
    Stack(children: <Widget>[
      calendar(),
      datefilter(),
 
    Container( 
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 450, 0, 0),
    child: FutureBuilder( 
    future: _getRecord(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<History>> snapshot) {
      // Check if the data has been received.
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
      
        // Return the widget and provide the received data.
        if(historyList.length!=0){
              return 
                Stack(children:<Widget>[
                Expanded(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount:1,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return ListTile(subtitle:Text("Total Working hours :  "+workinghours,style:TextStyle(fontSize: 25,color:Colors.red)));})),


               //here the listtile are building and i used SingleChildScrollView, but it is not working
                 SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child:Expanded(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Stack(
                              overflow: Overflow.visible,
                              children: <Widget>[
                            ListTile(
                           leading:  CircleAvatar(
                             radius: 25,
                            backgroundColor:Color(int.parse(annualboxcolor)),
                            child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 0),
                              child:Column(children: <Widget>[
                              
                              Text(snapshot.data[index].date[1].toString(),style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color:Colors.white),),  
                            ]
                            
                            ),
                          )),
                          title: Text(snapshot.data[index].date),
                          isThreeLine: true,
                          subtitle:Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                              Text(snapshot.data[index].timeIn+" To "+snapshot.data[index].timeOut,
                                  ),
                          ],
                      ) 
                      Divider(color: Colors.grey,height: 10,),

                          ]);
                        },
                      )))

              ]);
        }
       
      }
```

When i remove the second `SingleChildScrollView` under the Container where i used future, it is not working in that case too, and if wrap the container with `SingleChildScrollView` it is still not working. and if i return it after this line `if(historyList.length!=0){` and calling `Stack` its child then it's still not working.

**Updated:**

```
body:SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: 
    Stack(children: <Widget>[   
      calendar(),
      datefilter(),
    Container(    
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 450, 0, 0), 
    child: FutureBuilder(  
    future: _getRecord(), 
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<History>> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        if(historyList.length!=0){
              return  SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child:Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount:1,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return ListTile(subtitle:Text("Total Working hours :  "+workinghours,style:TextStyle(fontSize: 25,color:Colors.red)));})),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 70, 0, 0),
                child:Expanded(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return SingleChildScrollView(
                              //overflow: Overflow.visible,
                              child:Stack(
                                overflow: Overflow.visible,
                                children:<Widget>[
                            ListTile(
                           leading:  CircleAvatar(
                             radius: 25,
                            backgroundColor:Color(int.parse(annualboxcolor)),
                            child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 0),
                              child:Column(children: <Widget>[
                              Text(snapshot.data[index].date[9].toString(),style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color:Colors.white),),  
                            ]
                            
                            ),
                          )),
                          title: Text(snapshot.data[index].date),
                          isThreeLine: true,
                          subtitle:Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                              Text(snapshot.data[index].timeIn+" To "+snapshot.data[index].timeOut,),
                          ],
                      )
                          ),
                          Divider(color: Colors.grey,height: 10,),
                          ]));
                        },
                      )))

              ]));
        }
       
      }
```

When i replace `Stack` with `Column` in the main `SingleChildScrollView` it is not displaying `calender()` widget output, that's why i am using `Stack`.

And it is saying this that i used incorrect use of Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
here are the logs

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type StackParentData.

Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a Stack widget.

The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the incompatible parent data was:
  RepaintBoundary ← NotificationListener<ScrollNotification> ← GlowingOverscrollIndicator ← Scrollable ← ListView ← Expanded ← Stack ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#c7d81] ← Semantics ← ⋯
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
```

please help how to fix it.

Comment: add neverscrollphysic() in main Singlechildscrollview also use column instead of stack and remove singlechildscrollview from listview and depending up on use flex:0,flex:1  to expanded widget,if none of them works show some design,i will help you give some outline

Comment: i followed what u said, but it is not scrollable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your **calendar** and **datefilter** widgets are constants I mean they are not scrolling so try to remove your both **SingleChildScrollView** and use Below code hope it's helpful to you, declare your Widgets inside **Column** instead of **Stack**

```
body:Column:(
  children [ 
    calendar (),
     datefilter (),
     Expanded:(
      child:FutureBuilder(),
      )
    ],
   ),
```

Comment: i am getting the renderflex overflowed error now

Comment: Ok try to add your Column Widget inside SingleChildScrollView

Comment: it is not working still, i updated my question with ur answer please check